# Sample with replacement, avoid repeats

Tags: r

I'm programming a game that consists on executing a function that takes a random person from a list and select a random topic from other list.

The main rule is:
- You can run the code all times you want but the code can not gives 2 times the same person

For the moment what I got is:

```
# Lists 
people = list('john','peter','alex')
topic = list('Finance','Ensurance','Retail')

Start<-function(people, topic){
  arg1 = sample(people,1)
  arg2 = sample(topic,1)
  return (list(arg1,arg2))
}
```

The crux of the question is: Ensure that each time the function "start" is run, the person p and p+1 are not the same. so, the result could be like:

John, Finance/ peter, Finance /John, Retail /alex, Finance
But never: John, Finance/John, Finance.

Comment: Do you mean they can never be selected again or just not twice in a row?

Comment: It's pretty unclear exactly what your requirements are. You could store previous draws. Or you could use `sample` just once per list at the beginning to shuffle the order and then just track and increment your current index. So I assume `Start()` can only be called three times?

Comment: what I mean, this game could be useful to select randomly a person to write a topic into a blog (for instance), so the topic could be repeated but not the person.

Comment: In what context: R console, shiny, or something else?

Comment: Yes, next step is adapt the code to shiny. I will post the code once finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably make a generate style function

```
people <- c('john','peter','alex')
topic <- c('Finance','Ensurance','Retail')

Starter <- function(people, topic){
  last.person <- ""
  function() {
     next.person <- sample(setdiff(people, last.person), 1)
     next.topic <- sample(topic,1)
     last.person <<- next.person
     return(list(next.person, next.topic))
  }
}

s <- Starter(people, topic)
s()
s()
s()
```

Here `Starter()` returns a function you can call to get a new sample. It keeps track of the last person chosen and excludes them from the list of possible draws. Note that I used simple vectors for the list of options rather than lists to make things easier.

Comment: that's it!, I thought by looping but your code is shorter, smart solution!